# PyTorch equivalent of `skimage.draw.polygon`?

Tags: deep-learning, computer-vision, image-segmentation

I'm trying to generate a masked image from a set of points that may or may not overlap.

When using `skimage.draw.polygon` it is possible to generate indices that correspond to filling an image with the points given by the coordinates.

I would appreciate some assistance in implementing a batched (PyTorch) based method of doing this.

Example:

```py
from skimage.draw import polygon
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

vertices = np.array([[5,2],[5,5],[2,5],[5,2]])
rr,cc = polygon(vertices[:,0],vertices[:,1],(25,25))

masked_image = np.zeros((25,25))

masked_image[rr,cc] = 255

plt.imshow(masked_image)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try out Kornia's [draw_convex_polygon()](https://kornia.readthedocs.io/en/latest/utils.html#kornia.utils.draw_convex_polygon):

```py
import torch
from kornia.utils import draw_convex_polygon
from skimage.draw import polygon
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

img = torch.zeros((1, 1, 25, 25), dtype=torch.uint8)
vertices = torch.tensor([[5, 2], [5, 5], [2, 5], [5, 2]]).unsqueeze(0)
color = torch.tensor((255,), dtype=torch.uint8)
out = draw_convex_polygon(img, vertices, color)

plt.imshow(out.squeeze(0).permute(1, 2, 0).numpy())
plt.show()
```